# get character after space of array value on javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have question about getting character of string after space where the string is value of array like this..

```
arr = ['aaa: 2' , 'aaa: 5', 'aaa: 6', 3 , 7 , 8];

output = arr.filter(function (p) {
            if (!Number(p)) {  // get string value 
               return p.includes('aaa').split(' ').pop();
            }
         });

console.log(output)
```

i got error "TypeError: p.includes(...).split is not a function"

if i remove the .split(' ').pop();

```
array['aaa: 2','aaa: 5','aaa: 6']
```

i just want the output like this

```
array [2,5,6]
```

can anyone who's have experience on same problem help me? i'm stuck.
thank you guys...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) return bool value, which has no method `split`
2. [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) takes:

> Function is a predicate, to test each element of the array. Return
> true to keep the element, false otherwise.

3. For your task you need to additionally use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const arr = ['aaa: 2', 'aaa: 5', 'aaa: 6', 3, 7, 8];

const output = arr
    .filter((p) => {
        return Number(p) ? false : p.includes('aaa');
    })
    .map((p) => Number(p.split(' ').pop()));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: perfect bro.. Array(3) [ 2, 5, 6 ]

Answer (score 2):

[Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function is intended to only filter an array, without modifications. To combine modifications and filetring use reduce instead:

```js
const arr = ['aaa: 2' , 'aaa: 5', 'aaa: 6', 3 , 7 , 8];

const output = arr.reduce((result, current) => {
            if (!Number(current)) {  // get string value  
               if(current.includes('aaa')) {
               return [...result, current.split(' ').pop()];
               }
            }
            return result
         }, []);

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, *.filter* is the wrong method to use here, it either expects a true or false to keep/remove the given item from the array. Use *.map* instead.

Secondly, *.includes* returns true or false so trying to split a boolean will not work

if you want to remove the numbers as mentioned in your last edit, filter first. Try this:

```
// first filter out numbers
const output = arr.filter(function(p) {
    return !Number(p)
}

// then get the numbers out
output = output.map(function(p) {
    if (p.includes('aaa')) { 
        return Number(p.split(' ').pop());
    }
});
```

Comment: output : array['aaa: 2','aaa: 5','aaa: 6']

Answer (score 1):

1. filter method return only conditionally some filtered values of the
   array.
2. includes method return boolean type value. So you can't use split method with a boolean type value.

if you want to get a customize array from your main array then you can use reduce method.

```js
const arr = ['aaa: 2', 'aaa: 5', 'aaa: 6', 3, 7, 8];

const output = arr.reduce((value, key) => {
  if (!Number(key) && key.includes('aaa')) {
    value.push(parseInt(key.split(' ').pop()));
  }
  return value;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const arr = ['aaa: 2' , 'aaa: 5', 'aaa: 6', 3 , 7 , 8];

const output = arr.reduce((acc, arrayValue) => {

    const [key, value] = arrayValue.toString().split(': ');

    if (key.includes('aaa')) {
      acc.push(parseInt(value))
    }
    
    return acc;
    }, []);

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a regex that groups the number, and then extracting it would work.

```
const regex = /aaa:\s(\d+)/
const matches = regex.exec(p)
return matches && matches.length > 0 && matches[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need the numbers from the array? Use `Array.map` and a bit of `RegEx` magic:

```js
console.log(
  JSON.stringify( ['aaa: 2', 'aaa: 5', 'aaa: 6', 3 , 7 , 8]
    .map( v => /:\s+\d$/.test(v) ? Number(v.split(": ")[1]) : v) ) );
 
// only numbers from strings?
console.log(
  JSON.stringify( ['aaa: 2', 'aaa: 5', 'aaa: 6', 3 , 7 , 8]
   .filter( v => isNaN(+v) )
   .map( v => Number( v.split(": ")[1] ) ) ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, try this:

```js
var arr = ['aaa: 2' , 'aaa: 5', 'aaa: 6', 3 , 7 , 8];

console.log(arr.map(el => {
   if(typeof el === "string") {
      return parseInt(el.split(": ")[1]);
   }
}).filter(el => el!== undefined))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the value is a string, you can use the following regular expression to extract the digit following the space e.g.

```js
/^\w+:\s(\d+)$/
```

Match group #1 will be the digit, you will just need to parse it to an integer.

```js
const transform = (arr) =>
  arr.map(val => typeof val === 'string'
    ? parseInt(val.match(/^\w+:\s(\d+)$/)[1], 10)
    : val)

console.log(transform(['aaa: 2' , 'aaa: 5', 'aaa: 6', 3 , 7 , 8]))
```